# Copies of $\mathbb{C}$ in Artin-Wedderburn decomposition

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let  $R = \mathbb{C}G$ be the group algebra. Show that the number of distinct group homomorphisms from $G$ to $\mathbb{C^*}$ equals the number of copies of $\mathbb{C}$ in the Wedderburn-Artin decomposition of $\mathbb{C}G$.

I cannot solve it and my tutor gave me a hint -- $f: G \to \mathbb{C^*}$ extends to a ring homomorphism $f': \mathbb{C}G \to \mathbb{C}$. The $Ker (f')$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{C}G$. But I cannot justify the hint and still have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By Wedderburn-Artin $\mathbb{C}G$ decomposes as a product of matrix rings $\prod_{i=1}^n M_i$. Now $\ker(f)$ is a maximal ideal (because of $\mathbb{C}$ on the right side) and thus $\ker(f)=M_1\times\cdots\times M_{k-1}\times M_{k+1}\times\cdots\times M_n$. And so $\ker(f)$ corresponds to some $M_k$ which is $\mathbb{C}$ by the first isomorphism theorem. But I'm not sure why the correspondence is bijective.

Comment: The kernels of the two homomorphisms extending $c\mapsto\pm i$ can be distinguished based on which of $c\pm i$ they contain. In general, the kernel of any irrep is the sum of all the *other* summands in the AW decomposition, as freakish notes.

Comment: @runway44 Oof, now there is what I overlooked... I had been looking at $(\alpha-\gamma)+(\beta-\delta)i=0$ and thinking it would imply the quantities in parens were 0, but of course that is not the case. Thanks.  Something had to give... I am sure I have seen this result before, I just don't recall its proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at it now it seems simpler than when I last read it.

Maschke's theorem tells us that $\mathbb C[G]$ is a semisimple ring, so every $\mathbb C$ linear homomorphism of $\mathbb C[G]$ into $\mathbb C$ splits it into a copy of $\mathbb C$ complemented by its kernel.

Basic Artin-Wedderburn theorem says that the simple images of $\mathbb C[G]$ necessarily appear in a given Wedderburn decomposition of $\mathbb C[G]$.  So together with the last paragraph, this gives the correspondence of homomorphisms with factors of $\mathbb C$ in the Wedderburn decomposition.

The final thing to convince yourself of is the correspondence between $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphisms $\mathbb C[G]\to \mathbb C$ and group homomorphisms $G\to\mathbb C^*$.

Of course, any $\mathbb C$ algebra homomorphism $\mathbb C[G]\to \mathbb C$ restricts to a group homomorphism $G\to \mathbb C^*$ because the $g$'s are all units in $\mathbb C[G]$ and have to map to units in $\mathbb C$ (because those nonzero homomorphisms have to map identity to identity.)

The thing that sounds like it is most blocking you is the other direction, that any group homomorphism from $G\to \mathbb C^*$ lifts to one from $\mathbb C[G]\to \mathbb C$.  This is easy to verify, and a standard fact, that $f:G\to \mathbb C^*$ is extended to $\hat f$ by the rule $\hat f(\sum\alpha_gg)=\sum \alpha_gf(g)$.  It is not hard to check that this map from $Hom(G,\mathbb C^*)\to Hom(\mathbb C[G], \mathbb C)$ is inverse to the restriction map, so that you get the correspondence you sought.